# Chart.js Legend Customization

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I was having some problem with self-customized chart legend for chart.js. This is how my doughtnut chart looks like:

As you can see, the legend at the side is not showing the colored-square icon. By right, it should look like this:

My HTML for the chart:

```
<canvas id="merchantChart" height="660" width="330"></canvas>
<div id="merchantLegend" class="chart-legend"></div>
```

This is the part where I set the color for each slice and override the default chart legend provided by chart.js:

```
var opt = {
      type: "doughnut",
      data: { 
        labels: labelData, 
        datasets: [{ 
        data: priceData, 
        backgroundColor:  "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
        borderColor: colorArr,
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        hoverBackgroundColor: colorArr
        }] 
      }, 
      options: options
    };

    if (merchantChart) merchantChart.destroy();
    merchantChart = new Chart(ctx, opt);

    merchantChart.update(); 
    merchantLegend.innerHTML = merchantChart.generateLegend();
```

As you can see, because I am setting the backgroundColor for each slice to be transparent, is there any way to generateLegend() based on the borderColor of each slice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`legendCallback`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) method can be used to manipulate how legend­*'s* labels are generated. so, using this you can customize legend­*'s* box-color as well *(such as, using datasets border-color instead of background-color)*, like so :

```
legendCallback: function(chart) {
   var ul = document.createElement('ul');
   var borderColor = chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor;
   chart.data.labels.forEach(function(label, index) {
      ul.innerHTML += `
        <li>
            <span style="background-color: ${borderColor[index]}"></span>
            ${label}
         </li>
      `; // ^ ES6 Template String
   });
   return ul.outerHTML;
}
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ ⧩**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'doughnut',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
      datasets: [{
         data: [1, 1, 1],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
         borderColor: ['#ff9800', '#e91e63', '#2196f3']
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      legend: false,
      legendCallback: function(chart) {
         var ul = document.createElement('ul');
         var borderColor = chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor;
         chart.data.labels.forEach(function(label, index) {
            ul.innerHTML += `
             <li>
                <span style="background-color: ${borderColor[index]}"></span>
                  ${label}
               </li>
            `; // ^ ES6 Template String
         });
         return ul.outerHTML;
      }
   }
});

legend.innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
```

```css
.chart-container {
   display: flex;
}

#legend ul {
   list-style: none;
   font: 12px Verdana;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

#legend li span {
   width: 36px;
   height: 12px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 5px 8px 0;
   vertical-align: -9.4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
   <canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
   <div id="legend"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome !!­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: The legend is not included anymore in the canvas, so if you try to save the chart image the legend is not included anymore.

Answer (score 2):

legend customize with table to display multiple values

```js
var data = [{
    value: 2755,
    usedValue:100,
    color: "#FFE135",
    label: "Bare Pipe"
}, {
    value: 2256,
    usedValue:200,
    color: "#3B5323",
    label: "Coated Pipe"
}, {
    value: 1637,
    usedValue:300,
    color: "#fc6c85",
    label: "Cement Lining"
}];
var str=""
str+='<table>';
str+='<thead><tr><td>Item Name</td><td>Scope</td><td>Used in Construction</td></tr></thead>';
str+='<tbody>';
$.each(data, function(k,v){
    if(k =>0){
      str+='<tr><td>'+ v.label +'</td><td style="background-color:'+v.color+'">'+v.value+'</td><td style="background-color:'+v.color+'">'+v.usedValue+'</td></tr>';  
    }
});
str+='</tbody></table>';
//debigger;
    var optionsPie = {
        scaleBeginAtZero: false,
        legendTemplate: str
    }

    var ctx = $("#top10ItemsChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var top10PieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, optionsPie);
$("#top10Legend").html(top10PieChart.generateLegend());
```

```css
    .topleft {
        margin-top: -4px;
        margin-left: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

canvas {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

.chart {
    border: 1px solid forestgreen;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.pie {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 0;
    // adjust as necessary
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
}

table td{border:1px solid #ddd; text-align:center; padding:5px}
.legend {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    // adjust as necessary:
    width: 48%;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .legend {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .pie {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.pie-legend ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
}

.pie-legend span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.pie-legend li {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.0/Chart.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="topleft">
        <h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items</h2>
        <br />
        <div class="chart">
            <div class="pie">
                <canvas id="top10ItemsChart" class="pie"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="legend" id="top10Legend">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Working Example : https://codepen.io/santosh-k1/pen/jOEXdZO`enter code here`